# Getting to Gatwick Airport from Hastings

Tags: uk, trains, public-transport, airport-transfer, industrial-action

I am on a trip in Hastings and this Tuesday (09/08/16) I need to catch a flight from Gatwick Airport which leaves at noon. Usually I catch a train which takes me directly to the Airport, however due to the strike being held by Southern Rail I will not be able to do so. Could you please suggest the best alternative option. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.southernrailway.com/download/42151.2/00-00-strike-map/ says you can get to London Bridge and presumably back out to Gatwick. Don't know how long it would take

Comment: Might be go go london by coach first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using South Eastern to get to London first, either Charing Cross or London Bridge. You can then either get the Southern Train direct from London Bridge (which will be packed), the Gatwick Express from Victoria, or a National Express coach from Victoria Coach Station (which takes longer, but might be more reliable...) The coach departs at 7:30 though, so you'd need an early train...